# Backbone is not defined online but work on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

This code work on *localhost* but it's not working *online*

I get this Error online:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/jquery.base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/filereader.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/html5slider.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libraries/backbone.nopersistence.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/share.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/mfanimated.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/models.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/startup.js"></script>
```

Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined`

Comment: do you have any not found errors in your dev tools network panel?

Comment: I have just this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined`

Comment: Do you have backbone on your server?

Comment: are you sure you have backbone javascript in `assets/js/libraries` folder? have you checked if javascript files are loaded correctly from the browser console?

Comment: Yes, I have it, I have deplaced all files by ftp.

Comment: The error is at `backbone.nopersistence.js:75`

This line is : `Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options, error) {...}`

Comment: Well... apparently backbone or any of it's dependencies is not correctly loaded. Check the network tab and see if they are loaded correctly

Comment: @jamal Please do not put code in the comments and instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46175710/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Check the network tab and I see that they are not loaded correctly.

The probleme is solved.

Thanks.

Comment: You should delete the question. As it stands, it is unlikely to help anybody as it's an incomplete question and the solution isn't relevant to the community.